# Simplest way to print a character on the screen in 8086 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Does anyone know the simplest way of writing a single character (or string) to the screen using 8086 real mode assembly (without an OS)?

I was thinking that it would be as follows, but that does not appear to work.

mov [0b800h], 'A'

Many thanks!

Nick

Comment: Without an OS, fine. But what about using BIOS functions?

Answer (score 1):

The usual would be something on this general order:

```
mov ax, 0b800h
mov es, ax
xor bx, bx
mov ax, 'A'
mov es:[bx], ax
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that real mode uses a segmented memory layout. Your mov uses ds implicitly so you need to set it up, something like this (untested):

```
    org 7c00h
    use16

    push    0b800h
    pop     ds
    xor     di,di
    mov     byte [di],'A'
```